# Relative path to parent directory in '/etc/profile' file of portable git on MS Windows

Tags: git, unix, relative-path

How can I specify relative paths in [Git's](http://git-scm.com/) `/etc/profile` file (specifically, a relative path to the parent directory of the one that git.exe is called from)?

---

### Background

I'm a huge fan of making your devel infrastructure as portable as possible - where *portable* rather means "*portable across MS Windows machines*" than "*portable across operating systems*".

Also, I came to love [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and it's MS Windows sibling [mysysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and thanks to this [article](http://markashleybell.com/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable.html) I was also able to change Git's default `HOME` (`C:/users/<username>`) directory to facilitate true portability of the whole thing (my devel tools are located on a flash drive and so is my portable "HOME" directory).

However, I'm still not totally there yet:

- Suppose a version of portable Git is located at
  `F:/apps/git/<gitversion>`
- The above article suggest to put the `HOME` directory that Git looks
  for directly below the above directory
  (`F:/apps/git/<gitversion>/home`).
- However, I would like it to be at `F:/apps/git/home`
- Therefore I thought that something like this might get me there: `HOME="/../home"` or `HOME="../home`", but Git keeps complaining that it can't find the directory. So I must be doing something wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Below this following code (Or after any code that dealing with `$HOME`)

```
if [ ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    printf "\n\033[31mERROR: HOME directory '$HOME' doesn't exist!\033[m\n\n"
    echo "This is an error which might be related to msysGit issue 108."
    echo "You might want to set the environment variable HOME explicitly."
    printf "\nFalling back to \033[31m/ ($(cd / && pwd -W))\033[m.\n\n"
    HOME=/
fi
```

Specifies the path, you need relative to `pwd`

```
# normalize HOME to unix path
# HOME="/Home/Edward" relative to git-bash
HOME="$(pwd -W)/../home"
HOME="$(cd "$HOME" ; pwd)"
```

You may add `cd $HOME` in the end of profile to start the working directory to HOME